# kafka x kinesis - design questions

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis

I'm studying system designs and data streams and got confused about when to use Kafka or kinesis, at first I thought that they worked together, but I'm still not so sure if that's correct

let's suppose I have a microservice to calculate a delivery fee(shipping) with thousands of requests per second and need to give a reply almost instantly

my idea was this:

```
ENDPOINT --> API GATEWAY --> LAMBDA FUNCTION(if I need to do anything with the API) -->
KINESIS(process the data stream) --> KAFKA(publish the events on a queue) --> 
MICROSERVICE THAT WOULD CONSUME THE KAFKA EVENTS AND RETURN TO THE USER
```

does this make sense?
Kafka and Kinesis work together or I'm misunderstanding the functionality of any service?
Should I remove the lambda function?

PS: there's no code for this problem, I'm just trying to learn more about how to design a system

Answer (score 0):

They can work together (there is a Kafka Connector that can copy the data), but it's often pointless, as your gateway / lambda / app should be able to directly publish to Kafka.

The only reason you might need to duplicate data between the two is while you're migrating between them